# Riesz functional calculus

Tags: complex-analysis

let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of invertible elements in Banach algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and suppose $\{A_n\}$ has a limit $A$ that commutes with each $\{A_n\}$ then show by example that $A$ need not be invertible

Comment: take $H^{\infty}$ on the unit disc and $A_N=f_n(z)=e^z/n$

Comment: $\mathcal{A}=\Bbb{C}$ and $A_n = 1/n$